# Laravel Route::group for Admins

Tags: laravel, routes, admin

I would like to authentificate some routes, if the user is admin.

```
Route::get( '/user/{data}', 'UserController@getData' );
Route::post( '/user/{data}', 'UserController@postData' );
```

Now, I made it inside the Controller:

```
public function getData( $data = 'one' )
{
    if ( Auth::user()->permission == 'admin' ) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}

public function postData( Request $request, $data = 'one' )
{
    if ( Auth::user()->permission == 'admin' ) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

I would like to make it with Route::group, but how can I do that in the routes.php?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [create middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) which will check if user is an admin:

```
class IsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->permission == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->route('some.route'); // If user is not an admin.
    }
}
```

Register it in `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'is.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
];
```

And then apply it to a route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'is.admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/user/{data}', 'UserController@getData');
    Route::post('/user/{data}', 'UserController@postData');
});
```

Comment: Yes, the prebuilt authorization mechanism in Laravel lets you do that even smarterly through `Gates`... See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a routes group and give it a middleware

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-groups

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Example:

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get( '/user/{data}', 'UserController@getData' );
    Route::post( '/user/{data}', 'UserController@postData' );
});
```

app/Http/Middleware/admin.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( Auth::user()->permission !== 'admin' ) {
            //
        } else {
            //
        }

    }
}
```